# Flask return two string for self

Tags: python, flask, flask-appbuilder

I have a flask app builder problem

Model

```
class Allusernote(Model):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    content = Column(Text(250))

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.content
```

view

```
  class Allusernote(ModelView):
        datamodel = SQLAInterface(PushAll)
        list_columns = ['id', 'content']
        @action("Notification","to All  Staff ","Notification?","fa-rocket")

        def getdata(self,data):
            return data
```

now I only can pass content to data, 
how can I pass id  and content  to view, when I use id return id, use content  return content

Answer (score 0):

i has found some simplte list the data

```
@app.route('/list', methods=['GET'])
def list():
    table = dynamodb.Table('users')
    articles = []
    if request.method == 'GET':
        # Get all articles
        response = table.scan()
        articles = response.get('Items')

    return render_template('index.html', articles=articles, title='List Articles')
```